# mysqli inner join: data not exist in other table

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables and I am using inner join to get the data from table.

```
 select b.pic,b.fname,b.lname, a.job_id, a.uid, a.job_title, a.description, a.city, a.position, 
        a.salary, a.looking_for,a.website,a.date
   from job_posting a 
  inner join users b
  inner join job_applied c on a.uid = b.uid and b.uid = c.uid
  where c.job_id IS NULL and c.uid IS NULL and a.looking_for = 'student'
```

Above query is not returning any data. It's empty.

Let me explain the table.

> job_posting - Contain job information.
>   users - contain user information who posted the job.
>   job_applied - contain user has applied for the jobs.

So, I want to get the jobs those are not applied. In Job_paplied table I have job_id and uid.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: got it. i need to create a fiddle for this then. thanks

Comment: Well, my advice would be to supply the 'three things'. That may or may not include a fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `inner join` try `LEFT JOIN` like:

```
select b.pic,b.fname,b.lname, a.job_id, a.uid, a.job_title,a.description,a.city, a.position, 
a.salary, a.looking_for,a.website,a.date from job_posting a  
LEFT JOIN users b  on a.uid = b.uid 
LEFT JOIN job_applied c  on b.uid = c.uid
where c.job_id IS NULL  and a.looking_for = 'student'
```

and try again.

Comment: getting error - #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'where c.job_id IS NULL and c.uid IS NULL and a.looking_for = 'student'

Comment: check if these column exist in the associated table or not?

Comment: @calculatingmachine Fixed.

Comment: no error but it is showing the data if job applied and exist in job_applied table.

Comment: there were 3 jobs i applied 1 but still i am getting 3 records.